# c pointer with function and money

Tags: c, function, pointers

Write a program to dispense change.  The user enters the amount paid and the amount due.   The program determines how many dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies should be given as change.  Ask the user for the two inputs (amount due and amount paid) in main() and then send these along with pointers to 5 parameters (dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies) to a function called change(), which will then calculate the number of each to give out.  Print the results from main().

What is wrong with my program now. it compiles with no problems but my answer are wrong really wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

//function prototype
void change( int *d, int *q, int *di, int *n, int *p, int paid, int due );

int main()
{
    //variables
    int paid;
    int due;
    int dollars;
    int quarters;
    int dimes;
    int nickels;
    int pennies;

    //reference variables
    int *d;
    int *q;
    int *di;
    int *n;
    int *p;

    printf( "Enter amount due: \n" );
    scanf( "%d", &due );

    printf( "Enter amount paid: \n" );
    scanf( "%d", &paid );

    change( &dollars, &quarters, &dimes, &nickels, &pennies, paid, due );

    printf( "Dollars = %d\nquarters = %d\ndimes =%d\nnickels = %d\npennies = %d", dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies );

    getch();
    return 0;
}

void change( int *d, int *q, int *di, int *n, int *p, int paid, int due )
{
    int dm;
    int qm;
    int dim;
    int nm;
    int pm;
    int modu;
    int modu2;
    int modu3;
    int total;
    int penniestotal;

    total = due - paid;

    penniestotal = total * 100;

    dm = penniestotal / 100;
    modu = penniestotal % 100;
    qm = modu / 25;
    modu2 = modu % 25;
    dim = modu2 / 10;
    modu3 = modu2 % 10;
    nm = modu3 / 5;
    pm = modu3 % 5;
}
```

Comment: Look at the order you're passing the arguments, and look at the order the function prototype declares.

Comment: at `change` : remove `int d;`, and modified to `*d = penniestotal /100;`. ditto.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c with the wrong answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606261/c-with-the-wrong-answer) -- different error, but virtually identical program, and the error of the linked question is existing in this one already as well (function `change()` not actually doing anything as far as the output of `main()` is concerned).

Answer (score 2):

You declare/define  function as

```
void change(int *d,int *q,int *di, int *n, int *p, int paid, int due )
```

and call as

```
change(paid,due,&dollars,&quarters,&dimes,&nickels,&pennies);
```

The first 2 params `paid` and `due` passed are integers while the function expects integer pointers.

Seems like you want to pass them as last and second last parameters.

Comment: declaration of 'int d' shadows a parameter that means there is another variable with that name right.

Answer (score 0):

Check your  function signature .

This should be the call:

```
change(&dollars,&quarters,&dimes,&nickels,&pennies,paid,due);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using call by reference  method by

```
change( &dollars, &quarters, &dimes, &nickels, &pennies, paid, due );
```

and the function definition is as

```
void change( int *d, int *q, int *di, int *n, int *p, int paid, int due )
```

so pointer *d points to 
pointer *d points to dollars

pointer *q points to quarters

pointer *di points to dimes

pointer *n points to nickels

pointer *p points to pennies

In the function there are some calculations , **but finally the value is not assigned to the pointers** so that it gets reflected in the main() function values. 
So finally at the end of the function *void change( int *d, int *q, int *di, int *n, int *p, int paid, int due )* add the below code also

```
*d=dm;
*q=qm;
*di=dim;
*n=nm;
*p=pm;
```

for more clarification on call by reference method refer to link : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_reference.htm